# How can I find example usage of specific unicode characters?

Tags: search-engine, text-search, unicode, text

I'm interested in learning how particular Unicode characters are used. I want a tool which allows me to search for a particular character or code point and then will show me that character and some adjacent text as it appears in published electronic documents. In other words, there are many services which provide example sentences with real-world usage of specific words, like [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/fervid.html), and I want a similar tool where I can lookup specific Unicode characters and find their usage in context.

I'm not particularly concerned with what kinds of documents are used for the [text corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus), both formal reports and informal web pages are acceptable. Adjacent context would ideally be about 40 characters of text (excluding [markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)) before and after the character in question.

I wonder if perhaps there is a way to construct a query to a [search engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine) to accomplish this task. However, search engines are usually based on searching for words, rather than characters.

Comment: There are lots of websites like that. Any specific character examples you want to look for? As there are way more websites describing e.g. Unicode emojis than there are websites describing random barely used characters. You need to be way more specific about the goal IMO

Comment: @Destroy666: How about ᵬ (U+1D6C)? I can't find any site giving me usage examples.

Comment: You're using completely wrong approach. If you want to find info about specific letters of some chosen scripts, Unicode websites are not something that'll help you 100%. From what I see it's some unpopular letter that isn't even Wikipediad. Maybe you'll find info in some Latin books. Probably ones related to whatever you're trying to analyze.

Comment: Unicode websites were your idea, not mine. For a more popular character, how about ŉ (U+0149)

Comment: No, you are asking about "specific Unicode characters" and that's where the usually reside. Should edit it to be more specific is what I'm saying all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get samples for many of the characters in the following sort of way.

The page at [List of Unicode Symbols](https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/table/) maps characters and codes to Unicode 'planes and blocks.' For instance, the character '9' is unicode 0039, and it's an element of 'Basic Latin.'

Now, going down the list, let's take Cyrillic, the alphabet used in Russia and other countries. The Universal Declaration of Human Rights has been translated into most of the languages of the world; hence, most Unicode characters are represented. I search for the UHRD in Russian at [the UNHR search link](https://www.ohchr.org/en/search) to find several possibilities, amongst them the one for Uzbekistan, I think it was.

Download the document, and you have a sample of Cyrillic.

I realise that this is not a direct answer to your question but hope it might be helpful. Best of luck.